# How to fade in/out individual Tiles of AnimatedSprite

Tags: android, animation, sprite, andengine, alpha

I have an AnimatedSprite, consisting of 2 Tiles:

```
BitmapTextureAtlas mAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(mEngine.getTextureManager(), 100, 100, TextureOptions.BILINEAR);
ITiledTextureRegion mRegion= BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createTiledFromAsset(mAtlas, mService.getAssets(), "image.png", 0, 0, 2, 1);
```

I can fade in the Sprite as a whole using a AlphaModifer:

`mAnimatedSprite.registerEntityModifier(new AlphaModifier(2, 0, 255));`

But that's not what I want. **I would like to fade in/out the individual tiles during an animation**.

While Frame1 is fading out, I want to fade in Frame2 in the meantime.

Is there a way to do this?

Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to fade in/out first frame from animated sprite, than second and so on?

Comment: Yes. While Frame1 is fading out, I want to fade in Frame2 in the meantime. I updated my question.

Comment: I think it is impossible to fade out one frame while fading in another, because the animated sprite is treated as one entity in alpha modifiers. But you can fade out completely first frame and then fade in second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure i understand this question 100% and since i can't make a comment with low reputation ill do it here.

Use 2 separate sprites rather then the 1 tiled sprite. Fade sprite A out while sprite B fades in.

Comment: That's exactly what I did, I was just hoping that something like this was already implemented in AndEngine. Thanks anyways!